# Bash script to check iptables rules for loop with if condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, iptables

I saved ports in an array that I wanted to check, then I'm running a for loop to check for the port in iptables rule list. I want to echo Ports that are not in the iptables list with msg not found. Tried to add an if condition inside the loop but not working.
here's the code: [Non-working ;) ]

```
#!/bin/bash
array=( 3306 1403 8080 443 22 )
for i in "${array[@]}"
pc=(iptables --list | grep $i | cut -d " " -f1)
do
if [ "${pc}" = "ACCEPT" ]
then 
echo "ok"
else
echo "Port not found"
fi
done
```

Error:

```
array.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
array.sh: line 4: `pc=(iptables --list | grep $i | cut -d " " -f1)'
array.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
array.sh: line 5: `do'
```

Comment: *What* doesn't work?

Comment: @BenjaminW. whole script. some syntax issues?

Comment: Indeed ... have you put it in [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) ?:)

Comment: the pc=... line should certainly be after to "do" keyword. And you probably meant pc=$(...) not pc=(...)

Comment: "The whole script doesn't work" could mean many things. Do you get an error? Unexpected output? What output did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

I am not attempting to syntax check the entire script, but there appears to me an obvious issue; you're assigning the pc evar before the do. This becomes very evident if you format your code with tabs. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=( 3306 1403 8080 443 22 )

for i in "${array[@]}"
pc=(iptables --list | grep $i | cut -d " " -f1)
do
    if [ "${pc}" = "ACCEPT" ]
    then 
        echo "ok"
    else
        echo "Port not found"
    fi
done
```

From the above, you can see that pc is not being set inside the for loop. Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=( 3306 1403 8080 443 22 )

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    pc=$(iptables --list | grep $i | cut -d " " -f1)
    if [ "${pc}" = "ACCEPT" ]
    then 
        echo "ok"
    else
        echo "Port not found"
    fi
done
```

Edit: Also, @tink (made it 1 minute before me) noticed there's a missing $ in the assignment of the pc variable. I've updated my answer to make that clear as well. HTH

Comment: Plus pc=$(...) not pc=(...)

Answer (score 0):

Two syntax issues:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=( 3306 1403 8080 443 22 )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    pc=$(iptables --list | grep $i | cut -d " " -f1)
    if [ "${pc}" = "ACCEPT" ]
    then 
        echo "ok"
    else
        echo "Port not found"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using a `while` + `read` loop and [ProcSub](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). Instead of embedding `grep` and `cut` inside the `for` loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array=( 3306 1403 8080 443 22 )

regex=$(IFS='|'; printf '%s' "${array[*]}")

while read -r pc port; do
  if [[ "$pc" = "ACCEPT" ]]; then
    printf '%s is Ok.\n' "$port"
  else
    printf >&2 'Port %s not found.\n' "$port"
  fi
done < <(iptables --list | grep -E "$regex")
```

---

Tested against a file that contains the following.

```
ACCEPT 3306
REJECT 1403
REJECT 8080
ACCEPT 443
ACCEPT 22
```

---

Change:

```
iptables --list | grep -E "$regex"
```

To

```
cat file.txt | grep -E "$regex"
```

Just to simulate the `iptables` command.

---

Output

```
3306 is Ok.
Port 1403 not found.
Port 8080 not found.
443 is Ok.
22 is Ok.
```

---

That is a minimal assumption from the output of `iptables --list`, adjust the pattern matching if needed but that is the idea.